# AWS Beanstalk Sample Application TravelLog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy the AWS Beanstalk Sample app - TravelLog. I follow their steps. But when I try to deploy it using their instructions I get an empty screen when I goto application homepage. I run on server , make a AWS elastic beanstalk environment and finish.

http://sanjanatravel.elasticbeanstalk.com

I even tried http://sanjanatravel.elasticbeanstalk.com/home.do

But nothing is working and I don't know what I am doing wrong as this is a sample app. Can anyone please tell me?

Thanks in advance.

p.s I currently I get a blank white page

Comment: Did you terminate the EB environment? URL seems not working.

Comment: Yes I am sorry I was trying to make a new application afresh and deleting all old environments and apps. Apologies.

Comment: I edited my and to include new URL

Comment: Which container type did you select? Java?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use following troubleshooting algorithm:

1. Go to managment console => elastic beanstalk
2. Check status of your environment it should be "green".
3. If status "gray" or "red" go to "events" find records marked as error. There you can find that some aws resources not created or application deployment failed.
4. If you find in logs error messages like: command execution failed etc then get logs from ec2 instances with help of beanstalk managment console. Also getting logs from ec2 instances can be useful if environment status "green", but application doesn't work.
5. If you didn't find anything in logs, try to connect to ec2 instance by ssh and perform analysis of the local logs. Important to know that elastic beanstalk publishes not all logs to managment console.

Comment: but if there was a problem with the code then It wouldn't work in local server right? it works in the local server and I checked the environment variable it shows it green.

Comment: If environment status "green" and application doesn't on beanstalk it can be caused by different issues like: not installed some dependencies, not enough some permissions, sources or artifacts places in wrong placed etc. Try to ssh to instance and check.